# Why is renderOrder only effective when the camera is away from the model for a certain distance?

Tags: three.js

I set the renderOrder fields to 1 and 2 for the two instances of css3dsprite, respectively, but renderOrder only takes effect when the camera is a certain distance away from these two instances.

[image]

[image]

I hope the yellow label will always cover the red label.

Comment: AFAIK, `renderOrder` has no effect when using `CSS3DRendererer`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have cancelled the setting of renderOrder and still have this strange effect.

Comment: Can you try to render the labels with `CSS2DRenderer`? This renderer does support `renderOrder`.